# Increase margin between tilde and line of fraction

Tags: math-mode, margins, fractions, tilde

I've written a document with some complex formulars in it. I find the distance or the margin between a decoration of a variable, in this case a tilde and the line of the fraction, in which it stands to be too small. Here is a screenshot to show what I am talking about:

[image]

The red arrow points to the very small margin between a tilde and the line of a fraction. Note that this is already quite zoomed in, so usually in 100% zoom, it would look like this:

[image]

So I'd like to increase the margin in general. If there is decoration on my variables below the line of a fraction, that should be calculated into how far below my variable stands / how much margin there is.

How can I change that?

**EDIT#1**

To reproduce the process of creation I used, you'd have to use a [Jupyter Notebook](http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). However, I'll paste the math-mode code here, maybe it's still the same, when you use different tools, since it's based on Latex anyway:

```
$c^{-}_k = \left\{\begin{array}{cl}
    \infty &\text{falls } \tilde{a}_{\sigma(k),j} \leq 0, \forall j \neq k\\
    \substack{\min\\j} \left\{ \frac{\tilde{c}_j} \tilde{a}_{\sigma(k),j}}: \tilde{a}_{\sigma(k), j} > 0, j \neq k \right\} &\text{sonst}
\end{array}\right.$
```

**EDIT#2**

The suggested adding of `\vphantom{\big|}` did bring improvement indeed:

[image]

(upper image after insertion, lower image before insertion)
The whole formular increased in size, but that was to be expected I guess. Quite an increase in size though. I am aware that this is a rather not so good practice, since I'd have to add a vphantom in every single fraction I ever write. If anyone knows another tex way of doing this for all formulars, I'd appreciate it, even if you can't reproduce the issue, if you know how to increase that space in general, please tell.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I can't reproduce the issue; can you please show a minimal example of code?

Comment: @egreg Thanks! Added my math-mode code for the expression.

Comment: What's Jupiter Notebook?

Comment: @egreg Jupyter is http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ : )

Comment: Sorry, the program doesn't seem to use TeX, but it just shares the syntax. The rendering is up to the program and we can do nothing on the TeX side. Try adding a phantom, for instance `\vphantom{\big|}` in the denominator.

Comment: @egreg I don't mind having a solution for how to do it in tex. It's just that in this instance I used the Jupyter notebook. I also use other tools like pandoc, which can use latex engines to render md files, according to a specified template. In that template I can do any latex code I want.

I'll try your suggestion on the notebook though, thanks. You might make that an answer and if nothing else comes along, I can make it the accepted answer, in case it works.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior in TeX, so it's a shortcoming of that utility.

Comment: @egreg Updated my OP. Which Latex-Engine do you use? With xelatex I can reproduce the issue. I default to using xelatex because of pdflatex not being able to handle for example Chinese characters (which has nothing to do with this specific issue).

Comment: I still think this is tex / latex related, as I only use standard math mode, which is then handed to a latex engine (xelatex in my case). Only because that handing over is done by another program, doesn't mean the problem isn't existing. Did you actually try it yourself? Then you'd see ...

Comment: If this is regarding the in-browser display, that's handled by MathJax. X∃LaTeX is only used for conversion to pdf (and only since version 5.0+), and all commands should work there.